# C++ mincore return vector every byte is 1

Tags: c++, mmap

I use [mincore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html) to judge memory by mmap open in memory or disk. but return a set vector. Why? In fact the result must be a all clear vector, but I get all set.

This is my code. Why is line 28 (`cout << "find" << endl;`) always skipped?

`/proc/pid/smap` can see RSS is 0, but mincore return total file in memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* pData1 = NULL;
    int fd1 = open("test_large_file_1", O_RDWR);
    if (fd1 == -1)
    {
        cout << "file error ..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    off_t size1 = lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (size1 == -1)
    {
        cout << "lseek error ..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    pData1 = (char *)mmap(NULL, size1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd1, 0 );
    if (pData1 == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        cout << "mmap error ..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    unsigned char *pVec = new unsigned char[size1 / 1024 / 4];
    if (-1 == mincore(pData1, size1, pVec))
    {
        cout << "mincore error ..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size1 / 1024/ 4; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 1000 == 0)
            cout << (int)pVec[i] << endl;
        if ((pVec[i] & 1) == 0)
        {
            cout << "find" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    close(fd1);
    munmap((void *)pData1, size1);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get whether an address by mmap opening in memory or not, veteran has some way?/
I need help.

Comment: The code must be included as *text* into the question.

Comment: You will copy paste the code, then select it, and press either ctrl+k, or the `{ }` button in the toolbar

Comment: why mincore return all 1 bit vector ?

Comment: Please add the necessary includes too

Comment: oh,thx!   first use .

Comment: can you also add print out the errorno if mincore returns -1

Comment: `pVec[i] & 1 == 0` is always false, `== ` has higher precedence than `&`, try `(pVec[i] & 1) == 0`

Comment: i try but always 1...

Comment: does size1 have a sane value? if you compiled in 32 bits, `off_t != long` and if you feed it a sufficiently large file, the result will be garbage

Comment: and did the mmap actually succeed? not sure what is supposed to happen for a file that is open but seeked to the end

Comment: so yes, this is a fairly short program, check all the assumptions and the error codes out of all calls...

Comment: i add judge when return ...but problem is exist .

Comment: Try hex-dumping `pVec1`. Is it all 0xFF bytes, or what?
Does it change if you actually access them mapped data, or stay the same?

Comment: each byte is 1,not 0xFF,

Comment: The code looks ok at a first sight but if you ran this program more than once then all the data can indeed be already in disk buffers and may be the system make it already available for the process right after the `mmap` call.

Are all bits set even on the first run after a reboot?

Comment: how to reboot?,we use a distance service .we can't reboot computer . I rerun my main,but i get same result,just now.I will get a new computer to test tonight..

Comment: yes.you are right. i try to open a new file. then ok ...thx,guys.

Answer (score 0):

I get a old file(don't open long time),mincore return a normal vector(has 0 and 1), but a new file(just now open or read ...),mincore return a all set bit vector.
This phenomenon is due to page cache, that will save recently page to cache, if a program repeatly open a file, the page of file will be get in memory .